# getting inf values in scan using pointcloud_to_laserscan indigo

Tags: ros, pcl, iai-kinect2, pointcloud-to-laserscan, depth-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

**-- See Update 2 --**

I am using [iai_kinect2](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2)(ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04) to get a depth cloud from my Kinect2 in the form `sensor_msgs/Image`. Then, it is converted to `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` using [depth_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc) to do all the filtering operations using pcl. Now, I want to use [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan) but I am having some issues in converting the `filtered_pointcloud` to `laser_scan`. It does not give any error but the output `laser_scan` contains only INF. There are many related posts like [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/188444/convert-point-cloud-data-into-laserscan-in-ros-indigo/) and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/209973/pointcloud_to_laserscan-indigo-setup-problem/). I can't use `depthimage_to_laserscan` because I need to merge multiple point clouds and do filtering. Also, I tried changing the `target_frame` to `kinect2_link` but that didn't help. Also, I tried changing some of the parameters but no change in the output `laser_scan`. Here is my launch file :

```
    <launch>
    
    <node pkg="kinect2_bridge" type="kinect2_bridge" name="kinect2" output="screen">
        <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    </node> 
    
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="standalone_nodelet"  args="manager"/>
    
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="point_cloud_xyz" args="load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz standalone_nodelet">
        <remap from="camera_info" to="/kinect2/sd/camera_info"/>
        <remap from="image_rect" to="/kinect2/sd/image_depth_rect"/>    
        <remap from="points" to="/kinect2/pointcloud"/>
    </node>
    
    <node pkg="kinect2_filtering" type="kinect2_filtering" name="kinect2_filtering" output="screen"/>
    
    <node pkg="pointcloud_to_laserscan" type="pointcloud_to_laserscan_node" name="pcl_to_laser" output="screen">
        <remap from="cloud_in" to="/kinect2/pointcloud_filtered"/>
        <remap from="scan" to="scan2"/>
         <rosparam>
                target_frame: kinect2_link # Leave disabled to output scan in pointcloud frame
                transform_tolerance: 0.01
                min_height: 0.0
                max_height: 1.0
    
                angle_min: -1.5708 # -M_PI/2
                angle_max: 1.5708 # M_PI/2
                angle_increment: 0.0523 # M_PI/360.0
                scan_time: 0.3333
                range_min: 0.45
                range_max: 4.0
                use_inf: true
    
                # Concurrency level, affects number of pointclouds queued for processing and number of threads used
                # 0 : Detect number of cores
                # 1 : Single threaded
                # 2->inf : Parallelism level
                concurrency_level: 1
            </rosparam>
    </node>

</launch>
```

I am unable to make `pointcloud_to_laserscan` work properly. Does anyone have any idea what is the issue here? Any help will be appreciated.

**Update 1 :**
When I changed `max_height: 5.0`, I get a `laser_scan` but it is completely wrong. Here it is :

```
header: 
  seq: 7653
  stamp: 
    secs: 1452114415
    nsecs: 194144000
  frame_id: kinect2_link
angle_min: -1.57079994678
angle_max: 1.57079994678
angle_increment: 0.0522999987006
time_increment: 0.0
scan_time: 0.333299994469
range_min: 0.449999988079
range_max: 4.0
ranges: [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 0.45063257217407227, 0.45248475670814514, 0.4535152316093445, 0.454106867313385, 0.45574814081192017, 0.45014896988868713, 0.45500892400741577, 0.4504481256008148, 0.45145583152770996, 0.450962096452713, 0.45117509365081787, 0.45415404438972473, 0.4528849124908447, 0.4500834047794342, 0.45053648948669434, 0.4508683979511261, 0.4519908130168915, 0.45469483733177185, 0.4522281289100647, 0.45500484108924866, 0.45522522926330566, 0.45422250032424927, 0.4566135108470917, 0.4510946571826935, 0.45335447788238525, 0.45148807764053345, 0.4525870084762573, 0.45198413729667664, 0.45033854246139526, 0.4502975344657898, 0.45032933354377747, 0.4510512351989746, 0.4511733055114746, 0.45179998874664307, 0.4508054852485657, 0.45005494356155396, 0.45013701915740967, 0.4505907893180847, 0.45257997512817383, 0.4503863453865051, 0.45146650075912476, 0.45116832852363586, 0.45020565390586853, 0.4511633813381195, 0.4503015875816345, 0.4507128894329071, 0.4509909152984619, 0.4540099501609802, 0.4507279098033905, 0.45697665214538574, 0.45599526166915894, 0.45608508586883545]
intensities: []
```

Ranges are either `INF` or very close to `range_min` (0.45). Here is the RVIZ image (laser scan is in RED) :

[image: image description]

**Update 2:**
This is my TF tree :
[image: image description]

Earlier my frame was `kinect2_ir_optical_frame` which I changed to `kinect2_link` but again I was having the same problem. Then, I created a new frame `kinect2_link2` like this :

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect2a" args="0.0 0 0.0 0.0 -1.57 1.57 /kinect2_link /kinect2_link2 100" />
```

and used `kinect2_link2` as my frame, then the problem got solved and I am getting correct `laser_scan`. Thanks @Akif for the help and noticing the problem!

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223521/getting-inf-values-in-scan-using-pointcloud_to_laserscan-indigo/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2016-01-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-06**:
Does your rviz screenshot include the original point cloud, or the filtered point cloud?

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2016-01-06**:
RVIZ screenshot is showing the filtered point cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like your point cloud readings are rejected to due some reason and all your laser message remains as `INF`.

It may be helpful to follow  `rqt_console` output of `pointcloud_to_laserscan_node` in **DEBUG** level to see the reasons for rejections. There may be an order of magnitude problem with your ranges and readings.

**Update:**

There may be a transformation problem with your frames. RGBD sensors should use `_optical` frames which has different axis orientation than the standard one. Please check [REP-103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) on this. If your "`kinect2_link`" frame is an optical frame, then you will get your laser scan on vertical plane since `pointcloud_to_laserscan` generates scans on **x-y plane**. This also explains the reason that when you change `max_height` your range is affected (z axis is forward on optical frames).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2016-01-08**:
Thanks @Akif! Yes, Transformation was the problem!

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-09**:
You're welcome!